# Google drive mime types is not correct (Google thinks that is not PDF?);

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api, google-api-java-client, google-drive-realtime-api

I get files from google drive(Using Java)
**Everything works!**  BUT, when I see pdf documents mime type

```
file.getMimeType()
```

it is something like that: **application/vnd.google-apps.document**
it is not **application/pdf**

Question 1: Why is my pdfs at google drive with mime type **application/vnd.google-apps.document**

Question 2:

I need to filter my document, in order to get only PDF documents:
but this does not works! Googel thinks that my PDF is "vnd.google-apps.document"!

```
 String mime ="application/pdf"; //works when I set vnd.google-apps.document
 String query="'"+id+"'" +" in parents and trashed=false and and mimeType="+mime;
 FileList files = service.files().list().setQ(query).execute();
```

Comment: When the PDF files were uploaded, were they uploaded with convert=true, or convert=false?

Answer (score 1):

I've been reading a number of comments recently that Drive PDFs have become editable. So my guess is that you uploaded your PDFs with convert=true, and so Drive has converted them to docs. To prevent this, make sure that convert=false.